# Entity Framework Core - Cannot remove optional nullable relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

Using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` version `5.0.7` and `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` version `5.0.7`, I'm currently stuck trying to remove a relationship and have that change stored. Assume two models:

```cs
public class Banana {
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Consumer? Consumer { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class Consumer {
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I'm able to assign a consumer just fine using

```cs
myBanana.Consumer = dbContext.Consumers.First(row => row.Id == 1);
dbContext.Update(myBanana);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

and that works just fine - the database is updated accordingly. However, once that is stored, trying to remove the reference again using

```cs
myBanana.Consumer = null;
dbContext.Update(myBanana);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

fails. After saving, the old value is still in the database, not `null` as I would expect. Interestingly, other changes to the banana are saved just fine.

I'm not sure if I'm hitting a weird issue with Nullables, or if I'm just missing something, so I'd appreciate some hints.

Comment: What is this  public int Consumer? Consumer { get; set; } How you could even compile it?

Comment: @Serge this is a nullable value type see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: @Serge pardon, mistake trying to simplify the model enough to make it fit. That should have been `public Consumer? Consumer { get; set; }` - edited accordingly. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue using [auto-generated foreign key properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#no-foreign-key-property), you have to make sure that the navigations are loaded. If they are lazy-loaded by default and you don't manually load them, the property will already be `null` before you try to assign `null`, so EF can't observe a change.

Loading the navigation with `.Include(banana => banana.Consumer)` works, and so does loading it via `dbContext.Entry(myBanana).Reference(banana => banana.Consumer).Load()`. After the relevant navigation items are loaded, `myBanana.Consumer = null` from the example in the question works as expected.

---

If you have a non-tracking entity to work with (for example because it was generated by Model Binding), you can either get a tracking entity, or change the value of the auto-generated foreign key shadow property directly:

```cs
dbContext.Entry(myBanana).Property("ConsumerId").CurrentValue = null;
```

which also works. This may be a little bit less polished since you depend on a string as the field name to be correct, but it can be a valid option depending on the circumstances.

Comment: Consider unaccepting the currently accepted answer and accepting yours. It's not :in addition" to it,  since "fix your classes" is not an answer for the specific question, and definitely not mandatory.

Comment: For the record, I filed a bug report upstream: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25217 so the maintainers can decide if this is an acceptable side-effect or something that should be addressed.

Comment: @IvanStoev Can only accept my own answer in 2 days, but will do so, because that's a good point. Thanks!

Comment: @Serge, With all due respect, you might notice that I explained the main issue in my answer, but also suggested a possible alternative if getting a tracked entity is not an option. It is absolutely not for you decide what people should and should not do -- especially if what I'm describing here is 100% covered by the official docs.

"A real profi" would accept that there are multiple ways to achieve a goal, each with their own merits. Yelling "it looks ridiculous", "a profi would be ashamed", and "fix your models" is not conducive to productive and respectful discussion.

Comment: @DennisSchubert I have deleted all my posts since they insult you. I didn't mean it, nothing personal.  I just posted my opinion.

Comment: The shadow property hack is the only thing that works for me; when I try to use `.Include(...` on my page, which is tracking/saving several records in a single post, I get the error: `The instance of entity type 'Person' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 13}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.`.  Kind of disappointing that EF Core does not have a graceful way to resolve this collision for you.